# Errors Using node.js CI workflow

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci.yml

I am receiving errors after running workflows in Github Actions using Node.js CI.  I believe the problem is with the yml file based on the following errors:

build (18.x)
Process completed with exit code 32.
build (16.x)
The operation was canceled.

build (18.x)
The following actions uses node12 which is deprecated and will be forced to run on node16: actions/checkout@v2, actions/setup-node@v1. For more info: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-06-13-github-actions-all-actions-will-run-on-node16-instead-of-node12-by-default/

build (16.x)
The following actions uses node12 which is deprecated and will be forced to run on node16: actions/checkout@v2, actions/setup-node@v1. For more info: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-06-13-github-actions-all-actions-will-run-on-node16-instead-of-node12-by-default/

The error is occuring on the "run npm test" step. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the yml file but it is mentioned in the links on the error codes:

Here is the yml file:

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x,18.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm start &
    - run: npm test
```

Comment: Have you tried to upgrading the GitHub Actions? For example migrate to `actions/checkout@v3` etc?

Comment: I did try that initially and just tried again and I actually get the same errors. Thank you for that suggestion though!

Comment: You would need to upgrade all of your legacy actions for example migrating to `actions/setup-node@v3`. This process is fraught with problems. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GitHub Actions are outdated and do not support Node.js `v16` or `v18` (which are the versions you are using, as evident from your matrix strategy). Hence why you get the error.

You can fix the error by using `actions/checkout@v4` and `actions/setup-node@v3`:

```
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
```

---

Both `actions/checkout@v2` and `actions/setup-node@v1` support only up to Node.js v12.

`actions/setup-node@v3` supports Node.js `18` since `v3.7.0`: https://github.com/actions/setup-node/releases/tag/v3.7.0